# Django/Python - Check a date is in current week

Tags: python, django, datetime, django-queryset

I would like to do something like this:

```
entries = Entry.objects.filter(created_at__in = current_week())
```

How to make it for good performance. Thanks!

Edit: I still have no idea for `current_week()` function.

Comment: Define `current_week` for your application.  Please write the lines of code required to define the first day of "current" week.  The first day of the next week would be easy, given that definition.  (Some folks debate whether weeks begin on Sunday or Monday and how offset from January 1st works.)  Please provide code to define `current week`.

Comment: "I still have no idea for current_week() function.  If you cannot define "current week", you cannot write the program.  The definition of current week **must** be written down in code.  If you cannot do that, you cannot write a test case and you cannot prove that your code works.  If you cannot get a definition of current week from users or a supervisor or the product owner, you cannot get this code to work.  Stop working now.  Get a definition.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use `__range`. You'll need to actually calculate the beginning and end of the week first:

```
import datetime
date = datetime.date.today()
start_week = date - datetime.timedelta(date.weekday())
end_week = start_week + datetime.timedelta(7)
entries = Entry.objects.filter(created_at__range=[start_week, end_week])
```

Comment: As S.Lott noted, there's various interpretations of "week". @DanielRoseman's answer here assumes the Python default of weeks starting on Monday.

Comment: wouldn't you use 6 instead of 7 for the timedelta? monday = 0 and sunday = 6

Answer (score 11):

Since **Django 1.11**, we you can use **[`week`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#week)** [Field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#week):

```
Entry.objects.filter(created_at__week=current_week)
```

It will give you the week from monday to sunday, according to ISO-8601.

To query for the current week:

```
from datetime import date
current_week = date.today().isocalendar()[1]
```

`isocalendar()` will return a tuple with 3 items: (**ISO year**, **ISO week number**, **ISO weekday**).

Comment: This answer is right for the question. I was looking how to know if a birthday is in the current week and for that it doesn't work. Because the same day of the month is in different weeks every year.

Answer (score 2):

Yep, this question is at 2 years ago. Today with more experiences, I recommend using `arrow` with less pain in handling date time.

Checkout: https://github.com/crsmithdev/arrow